# Integral equation with fixed boundaries

Tags: integration, self-learning, integral-equations

How to solve integral equation 
$$
f(x) = 1 + \int_0^1 f(x-t) dt
$$
for $x\geq 1$ and we also know that $f(x) = e^x-1$ for $x \in (0,1) $? I would like to obtain solution for $x \in [2,3]$ without integral, or is there any way how can I plot it without having exact formula?

Comment: It might not be helpful at all but I have a feeling that you need to use Leibniz Formula. First substitute something like $u = x - t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=1+\int_{0}^{1} f(x-t) dt$ by changing variable $$  f(x)=1-\int_{x-1}^{x} f(y) dy  \Rightarrow f(x)=1-\int_{0}^{x} f(y) dy+\int_{0}^{x-1} f(y) dy \Rightarrow \\
f'(x)=f(x-1)-f(x),$$
so you get the following delay differential equation
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
  f'(x)=f(x-1)-f(x), \\
  f(x)=e^x-1, x \in (0,1).
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
you can solve it by method of steps.